# Django not getting id from the url parameter

Tags: python, django

i have these serializer on Django

```
class CarManagerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Manager
        fields = '__all__'
```

and this view class

```
class CarManagerViewSet(APIView):
    allowed_methods = ('GET',)

    def get(self, request, manager_id = None):
        if manager_id is None:
            managers = Manager.objects.all().order_by('-name')
            serializer = CarManagerSerializer(managers , many=True)
            serializer_data = serializer.data
            return Response(serializer_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            managers = Manager.objects.get(id = manager_id).select_related('cars')
            serializer = CarManagerSerializer(managers , many=True)
            serializer_data = serializer.data
            return Response(serializer_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

im trying to get the manager by its manager id

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/carmanagers/3
```

but the manager_id wont get passed to the view, i keep getting 'None'
where did i miss ?
below is the url

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(
        r'carmanagers/(?P<manager_id>[0-9]+)/$',
        CarManagerViewSet.as_view(),
        name='car-managers'
    ),
    url(
      r'carmanagers',
      CarManagerViewSet.as_view(),
      name='car-managers'
    ),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that there is no slash at the end of your path, so the first path will not match immediately, but the second path *will* match, because of lack of *anchors*. This means that your `r'carmanagers'` path will match each time the path *contains* `carmanagers`. You should add a start and end anchor:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(
        r'carmanagers/(?P<manager_id>[0-9]+)/$',
        CarManagerViewSet.as_view(),
        name='car-managers'
    ),
    url(
      # ↓   anchors  ↓
      r'^carmanagers/$',
      CarManagerViewSet.as_view(),
      name='car-managers'
    ),
]
```

---

> **Note**: As of [django-3.1](/questions/tagged/django-3.1), [**`url(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#url) is
> deprecated in favor of [**`re_path(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/re-path).
> Furthermore a new syntax for paths has been introduced with path converters: you
> use [**`path(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/path) for that.